# Declaring 'static' variable for Go unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have couple of packages and their unit tests. Each unit test opens a port and listens on it. Sequential running those tests result in `port in use` errors.

What I need is something similar to `static` variable in C++. One counter variable which will **preserve** its value in each unit test call. I will open subsequent ports for each unit test.

I'm doing this for opening subsequent ports for Nomad. They already use it in their codebase (https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/blob/master/testutil/server.go#L30) however offset is not preserved at each unit test.

Here is sample code to reproduce the issue:

A.go

```
package a

var Offset uint64
```

A_test.go

```
package a

import "testing"

func TestVar(t *testing.T) {
    Offset = Offset + 1
    t.Log(Offset)
}
```

B_test.go

```
package b

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/test/test/a"
)

func TestVar(t *testing.T) {
    a.Offset = a.Offset + 1
    t.Log(a.Offset)
}
```

Run tests:

```
$ go test -v ./...
=== RUN   TestVar
--- PASS: TestVar (0.00s)
        A_test.go:7: 1
PASS
ok      github.com/test/test/a  0.005s
=== RUN   TestVar
--- PASS: TestVar (0.00s)
        B_test.go:11: 1
PASS
ok      github.com/test/test/b  0.007s
```

Comment: It should as is in nomad code.

Comment: That's a package level variable, it's only incremented and not being "reset" between individual tests. Are you sure you're properly shutting down the server?

Comment: Server is shut down by `defer TestServer.Stop()` at each test. See: https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/blob/master/testutil/server.go#L213 . Even though they are in different package, it seems go test is running these in different environments thus value is not being preserved.